# Procedure Type Influence On Outcome: TypeName and TypeOf Behaving Differently Inside Subs and Functions

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

Working with Win64, VBA7 32bits on a simple combo of procedures to do things to an instance of Internet Explorer (IE instance), I've found that:

a. the function correctly identifies the IE instance type as IWebBrowser2;

b. the sub incorrectly identifies the IE instance type as String.

Would anyone gently share why?

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub SimpleTest()
    Dim iemIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim oDummy As Object

    Set ieIE = New InternetExplorer

    Set oDummy = mahFunction(ieIE)

    mahSub (ieIE)

    ieIE.Quit
End Sub

Function mahFunction(InternetExplorerThatHasMahObject As Variant) As Object
    Dim sFunctionTypeName As String
    Dim bFunctionTestIE As Boolean, bFunctionTestIEM As Boolean

    sFunctionTypeName = TypeName(InternetExplorerThatHasMahObject) 'returns "IWebBrowser2"
    bFunctionTestIE = TypeOf InternetExplorerThatHasMahObject Is InternetExplorer 'returns True
    bFunctionTestIEM = TypeOf InternetExplorerThatHasMahObject Is InternetExplorerMedium 'returns True

    MsgBox sFunctionTypeName & ", " & bFunctionTestIE & ", " & bFunctionTestIEM

    Set mahFunction = Nothing
End Function

Sub mahSub(InternetExplorerToWaitFor As Variant)
    Dim sSubTypeName As String
    Dim bSubTestIE As Boolean, bSubTestIEM As Boolean

    sSubTypeName = TypeName(InternetExplorerToWaitFor) 'returns "String"
    bSubTestIE = TypeOf InternetExplorerToWaitFor Is InternetExplorer 'returns False
    bSubTestIEM = TypeOf InternetExplorerToWaitFor Is InternetExplorerMedium 'returns False

    MsgBox sSubTypeName & ", " & bSubTestIE & ", " & bSubTestIEM
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `mahSub (ieIE)` to `mahSub ieIE` - putting brackets around it is forcing it to be converted from an object to the object's default property.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, sorry for wasting your time, @YowE3K.
*Feeling deeply dumb*
This post should be shut down.

Comment: :D (We've all been there!)